# How to apply toolbar-like styling to round textured buttons in a custom view

Tags: cocoa, toolbar, osx-lion, nsbutton

How do you apply toolbar-like styling to round textured buttons in a custom view?

Here's some more background:

Apple's human interface guidelines say to use controls with round textured styling in the window frame (the toolbar or the bottom bar): http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Controls/Controls.html (under "Window-Frame Controls").

When you use these controls in the window frame, Mac OS X Lion applies a relatively strong gradient to the controls when the window is active (about 95% grey to 80% grey), and almost no gradient at all when the window is inactive (about 95% grey to 93% grey). In other words, when the window is inactive, toolbar controls look flat.

When you use these controls outside of the window frame (say, in a custom view directly below the toolbar), Mac OS X Lion applies different styling. Most important for me, Lion applies a relatively strong gradient to the controls even when the window is inactive, so the controls in the custom view look out of place next to the toolbar controls on an inactive window.

There appears to be some way to get the right look for these controls even in a custom view. For example, the format bar in Pages, and the format bar in Mail when you're composing a message (both right below the toolbar).

Does anyone know how to achieve the correct look for these controls?